# "TypeError: this.setAuthHeaders is not defined"

Tags: node-red

After generating a node from a swagger file with nodered generator and when i try to execute a POST request from the new node, i get the following error:
"TypeError: this.setAuthHeaders is not a function"

Anyone has a hint?

the swagger file obviously doesn't contains any security rules

Comment: Have you added a debug node, set to print the entire msg, to show what is being POSTed?